# Changed the "Site URL" associated with my Visual Studio project and can no longer deploy?

Tags: content-type, visual-studio

I had been working with a custom content type in one of my development site collections and everything was working fine.  I then tried setting the "Site URL" in my project I started getting this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The content
>   type with Id
>   0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D00686902DCEDA048E5B29BDA9E09CD73FD
>   defined in feature {9d4762bf-a969-4b05-8110-811e329996ad} was found in
>   the current site collection or in a subsite.

So I switched back to the old "Site URL" and tried to retract but got the error:

> Feature '9d4762bf-a969-4b05-8110-811e329996ad' is not activated at
>   this scope.

What would be the proper way to deploy to the new Site URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom content types thru features can be very finicky... I think you need to ALWAYS retract before re-deploying elsewhere.

As far as your issue goes, I think you can try setting your URL back to the original and re-deploying. Once it deploys successfully, then retract it.

I think you're getting Error #1 because it was installed in the content database already (so the guid exists) even though it isn't activated.